# Start and End of Any Interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to detect the start and end of any interaction? I noticed that there are methods like touchesBegin and touchesEnd but those are only for touch events. Is there a general method for all possible interactions like panning, zooming, touch, etc.?

I just need to know when an interaction starts and ends.

Comment: Panning and zooming are also touch events.

Comment: [iOS Event Handling Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html) should answer all of the above doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to hook up [`UIGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) subclasses for the events you are interested in:

- `UITapGestureRecognizer`
- `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`
- `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`
- `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`
- `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

From there, you can check the recognizer's state and perform any logic you need once the interaction begins (`UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`) and when it ends (`UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`, `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed`).

You'll most likely want to use some mutual exclusion so that when the first type of gesture is recognized you remove the other recognizers to ensure they don't step on each others toes.  You can then re-add all of them when the first recognized gesture ends.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use this code:

```
 if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
```

or:

```
 if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
```